# With which meaning

Tags: relative-clauses

"The mechanism with which growth is controlled is called the limiter". What is the meaning of "with which" in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

"*The mechanism with which growth is controlled is called the limiter."*

In the sentence, *with which* is an attributive clause. It essentially transforms the sentence structure of "*Growth is controlled with the mechanism called the limiter*". It is directly relating the limiter as the mechanism that controls growth.

Comment: I think what you say is potentially misleading, since the **relative** clause is not just "with which" but "with which growth is controlled".